# Invalid Cloudinary Configuration

Tags: node.js, file, config, cloudinary, keystonejs

I'm new to keystone and am trying to deploy a simple website template to familiarise myself with the technology, I have downloaded all the necassary modules and created a keystone.js file and package.json file with all the dependencies. However, when I attempt to run keystone.js in the terminal I get the following:

```
 Error: Invalid Configuration

 CloudinaryImage fields (Gallery.heroImage) require the "cloudinary config" option to be set.

 See http://keystonejs.com/docs/configuration/#cloudinary for more information.
```

I have set up an account with cloudinary and used npm install to ensure it is installed in the system but it obviously can't find the configuration. I assume there is a simple solution to this and that I simply have to put my configuartion fields in the right place of the code but I can't seem to find any instructions as to where to insert my account details. Any help would be appreciated and please let me know if I have omitted any important code.

keystone.js:

```
    require('dotenv').load();

    // Require keystone
   var keystone = require('keystone'),
handlebars = require('express3-handlebars');


    // Initialise Keystone with your project's configuration.
   // See http://keystonejs.com/guide/config for available options
   // and documentation.


   keystone.init({

'name': 'Tech Website',
'brand': 'Tech Website',

'less': 'public',
'static': 'public',
'favicon': 'public/favicon.ico',
'views': 'templates/views',
'view engine': 'hbs',

'custom engine': handlebars.create({
    layoutsDir: 'templates/views/layouts',
    partialsDir: 'templates/views/partials',
    defaultLayout: 'default',
    helpers: new require('./templates/views/helpers')(),
    extname: '.hbs'
}).engine,

'auto update': true,
'session': true,
'auth': true,
'user model': 'Yes',
'cookie secret': 'pUO>=q^~Z.h]~pO"k;:]dTcTb:6pT3Xyassxdk>9K]7J0MGqSWWr;$rs6lG<XLdB'

});

    // Load your project's Models

keystone.import('models');

    // Setup common locals for your templates. The following are required for the
   // bundled templates and layouts. Any runtime locals (that should be set uniquely
  // for each request) should be added to ./routes/middleware.js

keystone.set('locals', {
_: require('underscore'),
env: keystone.get('env'),
utils: keystone.utils,
editable: keystone.content.editable
    });

    // Load your project's Routes

    keystone.set('routes', require('./routes'));

    // Setup common locals for your emails. The following are required by Keystone's
    // default email templates, you may remove them if you're using your own.

    // Configure the navigation bar in Keystone's Admin UI

    keystone.set('nav', {
'posts': ['posts', 'post-categories'],
'galleries': 'galleries',
'enquiries': 'enquiries',
'yes': 'yes'
});

// Start Keystone to connect to your database and initialise the web server

.start();
```

package.json

```
{
 "name": "tech-website",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
  "keystone": "~0.2.27",
  "async": "~0.9.0",
  "underscore": "~1.7.0",
  "moment": "~2.8.1",
  "express3-handlebars": "~0.5.0",
  "handlebars": "^2.0.0-alpha.2",
  "dotenv": "0.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  "grunt": "~0.4.4",
  "grunt-express-server": "~0.4.17",
  "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1",
  "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.7.1",
  "jshint-stylish": "~0.1.3",
  "load-grunt-tasks": "~0.4.0",
  "grunt-node-inspector": "~0.1.5",
  "time-grunt": "~0.3.1",
  "grunt-concurrent": "~0.5.0",
  "grunt-nodemon": "~0.2.1",
  "open": "0.0.5"
},
  "engines": {
  "node": ">=0.10.22",
  "npm": ">=1.3.14"
},
"scripts": {
"start": "node keystone.js"
},
"main": "keystone.js"
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can configure `Cloudinary` in your KeystoneJS app.

One option is to set the `CLOUDINARY_URL` environment variable. You can do this in your `.env` file, since you're using `dotenv`.

```
CLOUDINARY_URL=cloudinary://api_key:api_secret@cloud_name
```

A second alternative would be to set the `cloudinary config` setting within your Keystonejs app.

You can do this either in your `keystone.init()`

```
keystone.init({
    ...
    'cloudinary config': 'cloudinary://api_key:api_secret@cloud_name',
    ...
});
```

... or using the `keystone.set()` method.

```
keystone.set('cloudinary config', 'cloudinary://api_key:api_secret@cloud_name' );
```

These were all detailed on the [KeystonsJS Configuration](https://v4.keystonejs.com/documentation/configuration/#services-cloudinary) page, but are not present anymore.

Comment: I did this but the in the keystone admin/gallery it's saying `No galleries found. `

Comment: I assume you used your own Cloudinary account. If you have never created/uploaded any galleries the Admin should say "No galleries found." Create a gallery and upload some photos.

Comment: By default cloudinary provide one photo! I also tried with cloudinary key from an example provided by keystonejs. It still shows the Same message

Comment: Keystone doesn't "automatically" pick up photos in Cloudinary. There must be a record in your galleries table pointing to the images.

Comment: i have create a Gallery model 

`var Gallery = new keystone.List('Gallery', {
 autokey: { from: 'name', path: 'key', unique: true },
 nodelete:true,
 nocreate:true
});`


`Gallery.add({
 name: { type: String, required: true },
 publishedDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
 images: { type: Types.CloudinaryImages }
});`

`Gallery.register();`

and this is how i set the config


`keystone.set('cloudinary config', 'cloudinary://333779167276662:_8jbSi9FB3sWYrfimcl8VKh34rI@keystone-demo' );`

`keystone.start();`

Comment: That looks fine to me. You still need to create a new Gallery and upload photos (from Admin) for them to appear in admin.

Comment: create new gallery from cloudinary?

Comment: Just looked at your code again. Noticed that you have nocreate:true in your list definition. Remove it and you should be able to create Galleries fro the Keystone Admin UI.

Answer (score 3):

Adding something -

Well what actually worked for me was when I placed the config setting part in the

keystone.init portion. using setters did not work for me.

```
keystone.init({
    ...
    'cloudinary config': 'cloudinary://api_key:api_secret@cloud_name',
    ...
});
```

Above code is the only one that worked flawlessly.

Comment: had a similar problem, worked as soon as I moved setters above init.

Comment: Also same here with success in moving setter ABOVE init. Got passed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I deployed to heroku. In **keystone.js** add a block to use environment variables:

```
if (keystone.get('env') == 'production'){
    keystone.set('cloudinary config', process.env.CLOUDINARY_URL);
    keystone.set('cookie secret', process.env.COOKIE_SECRET);
    keystone.set('mandrill api key', process.env.MANDRILL_API_KEY);
}
```

Then set the environment variables on your heroku instance through the command line:

```
$ heroku config:set MANDRILL_API_KEY=YOUR_API_KEY
$ heroku config:set CLOUDINARY_URL=cloudinary://api_key:api_secret@cloud_name
$ heroku config:set NODE_ENV=production
$ heroku config:set COOKIE_SECRET=YOUR_COOKIE_STRING
```